# is ther any way carryout backward pagination in elasticsearch(with golang )

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

Pagination is done using scroll_api, as a result, is more than 10k

```
http://localhost:9200/all_assets/_search?scroll=10m

{
  
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "?.keyword": "?"
        }
    ]
```

To get next further result using this

```
localhost:9200/_search/scroll?pretty
{
    "from":10,
    "scroll": "10m",
    "scroll_id": "FGluY2x1ZGVfY29udGV4dF91dWlkDXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBFFNmNUJLM1VCaFRQeUhJQlNPamRqAAAAAAAAAAIWNE0tSDZYY2tSanFyUk95VXl0enpsZw=="
}
```

1 ] If we execute this will get the next 10 records and 2] we execute again we will get the next 10 records,
**is there is any way to get the previous 10 records**, have tried using from and size.
**Is there any way to make it with backward-compatible**.

Not getting the previous result it's providing the next 10 records if we execute with scroll_id url and wanted to make pagination forward and backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

A `scroll` is one way, just forward. You cannot go back. If you want to have backward, you need to use `search API` with `from` and `size` parameters.